# PhantomJS crashes after 150-180 urls

Tags: crash, phantomjs, httprequest

My script works fine so far, loading every page in the text file line by line in sequentiell order (page.open is asynchron and the page object is global = overwriting on new requests, it's a big clusterfuck running multiple page.open() at once), matching every request for a specific domain and printing JSON values from it.

But if I use a .txt-file with over ~150 links, it just crashes every time, mostly with no error message and with no crash dump like this:

> PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at
>   http://phantomjs.org/crash-reporting.html and file a bug report at
>   https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new.
>   Unfortunately, no crash dump is available.
>   (Is %TEMP% (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp) a directory you cannot write?)

I can reproduce that easily if I run it multiple times, doesn't matter if I do it at once or one after one.
How can I prevent the crashes? My script is useless if Phantom can't handle that.

But sometimes I get a crash dump:

> PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at
>   http://phantomjs.org/crash-reporting.html and file a bug report at
>   https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new.
>   Please attach the crash dump file:
>   C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\a4fd6af6-1244-44d3-8938-3aabe298c2fa.dmp

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3qi5ed33mbblie/500%20links%20-a4fd6af6-1244-44d3-8938-3aabe298c2fa.dmp?dl=1

https://www.dropbox.com/s/najdz9fhdexvav1/500%20links-%2095ebab5c-859b-40e9-936b-84967471779b.dmp?dl=1

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d2t8rtev85yf96/500%20links%20-%20d450c8e1-9728-41c7-ba52-dfef466f0222.dmp?dl=1

And in rare cases I even get an error message, Process Explorer says the process has a maximum of 21 threads at once

> QThread::start: Failed to create thread ()

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.open('500sitemap.txt', 'r');
var webPage = require('webpage');
var i = 1;
var hasFound = Array();
var hasonLoadFinished = Array();

function handle_page(line) {
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.loadImages = false;
page.open(line, function() {});

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    var match = requestData.url.match(/example.de\/ac/g)
    if (match != null) {
        hasFound[line] = true;
        var targetString = decodeURI(JSON.stringify(requestData.url));
        var klammerauf = targetString.indexOf("{");
        var jsonobjekt = targetString.substr(klammerauf,     (targetString.indexOf("}") - klammerauf) + 1);
        targetJSON = (decodeURIComponent(jsonobjekt));
        var t = JSON.parse(targetJSON);
        console.log(i + "   " + t + "       " + t['id']);
        request.abort;
    } else {
        //hasFound = false;
        return;
    }

};
page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {    
    if (!hasonLoadFinished[line]) {
        hasonLoadFinished[line] = true;
        if (!hasFound[line]) {
            console.log(i + " :NOT FOUND: " + line);
            console.log("");
        }
        i++;
        setTimeout(page.close, 200);
        nextPage();
    }
}
};

function nextPage() {
var line = stream.readLine();
if (!line) {
    end = Date.now();
    console.log("");
    console.log(((end - start) / 1000) + " Sekunden");
    phantom.exit(0);
}
hasFound[line] = false;
hasonLoadFinished[line] = false;
handle_page(line);
}

start = Date.now();
nextPage();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/edit crashed with 1.9.8 after 3836 links .... back to start ...........

Seems like the problem lies into the 2.0 version. Tested 1.9.8 out of frustration and - it works, 60% less RAM used, no crashes with 1000 Urls.

Crash report on github is done, what a relief, it works.